# Gradient of nodal basis function on triangle

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Given a triangle with vertices $N=\{A,B,C\}$, where the triangle is defined to be the convex hull of those vertices, the nodal basis function is defined to be $$\phi_P(x) = \begin{cases} 1, x = P \\ 0, x \in N \setminus \{P\} \end{cases}$$

Followed by linear interpolation between these values, so that $\phi_P \in \mathcal{P}_1$.

So I would assume one needs the linear equation between 1 and 0 for all points on the edge between these two points. You could solve this line as the intersection of two planes, but this would get messy. Is there a straightforward way way to get the gradient for this function?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is the following.
You can write the basis function as 
$$
\phi_P(x,y) = \phi_P(x_P,y_P) + \left( \nabla \phi_P \right)_x (x-x_P) + \left( \nabla \phi_P \right)_y (y-y_P)
$$
which is a Taylor series which is exact because \phi_P is a linear polynomial. Moreover, $\nabla \phi_P$ is a constant vector.
So you can easily write down two linear equations which make $\phi_P$ vanish at the other two vertices of the triangle and get the formula for the desired gradient.